# Which characters in One Punch Man have regeneration abilities?

Tags: one-punch-man

I was reading the *One Punch Man* wikia and it apparently claimed Metal Bat has some sort of regeneration abilities which I don't know if it's true. I actually didn't think he had those. If it's true and he actually does have them, it made me wonder if there could be several more.

Which characters in One Punch Man aside from the well-known ones like Melzargard, Boros and Zombie Man have regeneration abilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wikia actually has a [page](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Regeneration) which lists all characters from the manga/anime that have regeneration.

- Boros
- Deep Sea King
- Demonic Fan
- Elder Centipede
- Melzalgald
- Mosquito Girl
- Pureblood
- Sludge Jellyfish
- Super Mouse
- Zombieman

Characters from the webcomic include,

- Black Sperm
- Fuhrer Ugly
- Garou
- Sweet Mask

It is noted that each regeneration ability varies among each being, some having a weaker versions that is 'able to regenerate fractured bones or mutilated body parts'. Furthermore, each

> has had different types of regeneration, different ways they have regenerated, how much time it takes to regenerate their bodies, and whether they recreate cells in their body or regroup cells back together.

Comment: Strange they dont mention Metal Bat when in its profile page they do "Increased Healing Factor: Metal Bat possesses the ability to recover from minor blood loss and fractured bones in a matter of days just by resting"  https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Bad

Comment: @Pablo Probably just an oversight or mistake by the contributors. I looked at that chapter they mentioned in the wiki and I see no info that says he has increased healing factor. I might be wrong, though...

Comment: It's unclear on where you're supposed to draw the line between "superhuman regeneration" and the "badasses recover quickly" trope.  Metal Bat is a stereotypical badass delinquent type. These days most people think of a regeneration ability as meaning you can recover from significant damage in a matter of seconds.  While the badass-recovery trope is more of an exceptional, but still wholly human ability that lets you recover from anything short of limb loss and death in a very short, but still longer-than-a-fight timespan.

Answer (score 0):

Pig God also has regeneration habilities. It's mentioned in manga #123

"In case of injuries, the natural healing properties of the energy in the fat will make him recover inmediately"